# Angular2 - embedding flash game - game shows up for a moment and disappears

Tags: javascript, flash, angular, angular2-routing

-------------------edit----------------------

I narrowed in the problem and it seems like a problem in the domSanitizer. I created 2 `<embed>` tags - one with the hard-coded path and one with the output of domSanitizer. the first one works perfectly and the second one isn't doing anything:

```
//working
<embed src="THE_HARD_CODED_URL" width="800" height="512" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"/>

//not working
<embed [src]="safeUrl" width="800" height="512" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"/>
```

---

I'm developing a website in angular2 which requires embedding flash games.
The problem is that when I navigate to the Game's view I don't see the game in the `<embed>` spot. If I force-refresh the site from within the game page - I see something there for a quick moment(I think it is the initial message from adobe before the game is loaded) and then it disappears.

Here is code samples - I have a list of games in my "game-list" component so if you click on one you are routed to a view for this specific game:

```
//game-list.component.html

    <a [routerLink]="['/game', game.id]">
       <img [src]="game.preview.thumbnailPath" />
    </a>
```

The route leads to the "game" component which looks like so:

```
//game.component.html

    <h1>{{game.name}}</h1>
    <embed [src]="safeUrl" width="800" height="512" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"/>
```

`safeUrl` is the output of DOM Sanitizer

```
//game.component.ts

this.safeUrl = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.game.embedUrl);
```

Needless to say I checked that all the data is passed correctly to "game" component - I printed `safeUrl` and got the desired link.

I'm pretty new to angular so maybe I'm missing a basic thing but I don't see it.

Thanks!